# PubSub Emulator - ( Support Proto Buffer publish/receive msg)

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I am developing a solution to use a common Proto Buffer library to send and receive msg using directly proto buffer serialized (ByteString) and deserialization from a (ByteString) directly into the same Proto Buffer Class. My solution until now it is not working. Just when I use a real PubSub.

Based on [The doc: Testing apps locally with the emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) information and more specific in the section [knowing limitations](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#known_limitations%5D):

- Emulator doesn't provide Schema support for protocol buffers.

Although, I am not using any schema definition in Topic/Subscription. Just using a common proto buffer library programmatically. I'm afraid there is a Pubsub emulation limitation and for this reason my solution doesn't work with the Emulator.

Bellow my Test Class any clarification we be very welcome.

```
package com.example.pubsubgcpspringapplications;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.alpian.common.pubsub.messages.OnfidoVerificationEvent;
import com.example.pubsubgcpspringapplications.config.PubSubTestConfig;
import com.example.pubsubgcpspringapplications.services.MessageRealGcpService;
import com.example.pubsubgcpspringapplications.util.DataGenerationUtils;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

//@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EmulatorPubSubWithSpringTest {

  @BeforeAll
  static void startUpTests() throws IOException {
    PubSubTestConfig.setupPubSubEmulator();
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  @Test
  void successfulTest() throws InterruptedException {

    var status = DataGenerationUtils.STATUS_COMPLETE;
    var result = DataGenerationUtils.RESULT_CLEAR;
    var subResult = DataGenerationUtils.SUB_RESULT_CLEAR;

    var documentReport = DataGenerationUtils.generateOnfidoDocumentReport(status, result, subResult);
    var facialSimilarityReport = DataGenerationUtils
        .generateOnfidoFacialSimiliratyVideoReport(status, result, subResult);

    OnfidoVerificationEvent.Builder builder = OnfidoVerificationEvent.newBuilder();
    builder.setCheckId(DataGenerationUtils.FAKE_CHECK_ID);
    builder.setApplicantId(DataGenerationUtils.FAKE_APPLICANT_ID);
    builder.setDocument(documentReport);
    builder.setFacialSimilarityVideo(facialSimilarityReport);
    OnfidoVerificationEvent onfidoVerificationEvent = builder.build();

    publishProtoMessageTest(onfidoVerificationEvent);

    MessageReceiver receiver =
        (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
          ByteString data = message.getData();

          // Get the schema encoding type.
          String encoding = message.getAttributesMap().get("googclient_schemaencoding");

          block:
          try {
            switch (encoding) {
              case "BINARY":
                // Obtain an object of the generated proto class.
                OnfidoVerificationEvent state = OnfidoVerificationEvent.parseFrom(data);
                System.out.println("Received a BINARY-formatted message: " + state);
                break;

              case "JSON":
                OnfidoVerificationEvent.Builder stateBuilder = OnfidoVerificationEvent.newBuilder();
                JsonFormat.parser().merge(data.toStringUtf8(), stateBuilder);
                System.out.println("Received a JSON-formatted message:" + stateBuilder.build());
                break;

              default:
                break block;
            }
          } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          consumer.ack();
          System.out.println("Ack'ed the message");
        };

    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
        ProjectSubscriptionName.of(PubSubTestConfig.PROJECT_ID, PubSubTestConfig.SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);

    // Create subscriber client.
    Subscriber subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();

    try {
      subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
      System.out.printf("Listening for messages on %s:\n", subscriptionName);
      subscriber.awaitTerminated(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
      subscriber.stopAsync();
    }

    Thread.sleep(15000);

  }

  public static void publishProtoMessageTest(OnfidoVerificationEvent onfidoVerificationEvent)
      throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    Publisher publisher = null;

    block:
    try {
      publisher = Publisher.newBuilder("projects/my-project-id/topics/topic-one").build();
      PubsubMessage.Builder message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder();
      // Prepare an appropriately formatted message based on topic encoding.
      message.setData(onfidoVerificationEvent.toByteString());
      System.out.println("Publishing a BINARY-formatted message:\n" + message);

      // Publish the message.
      ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(message.build());
      //System.out.println("Published message ID: " + future.get());

    } finally {
      if (publisher != null) {
        publisher.shutdown();
        publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Note: Please, I just copied some sniped code from google tutorial and modified it. I don't want to use JSON just publish and receive msg using proto files.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say that your solution doesn't work, what do you mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, For some reason,  I can publish '''
Published message ID: 3372434705961298
'''
But I can't receive the msg 
'''
Listening for messages on sub-two:
2021-10-28 14:12:57.210 ERROR 4570 --- [bscriber-SE-2-1] c.g.c.p.v.StreamingSubscriberConnection  : terminated streaming with exception
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=sub-two).
'''
However, the subscription was created. I know that because I can do it using in another test. But using Json format and
PubSubTemplate.

Comment: Although, Your error message indicates that the subscription may not be created, maybe the application is accessing the wrong pub sub instance. add the following line too get the environment details and print it to check if you are on the right PubSub instance : `string emulatorHostAndPort = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");`

Comment: All my classes are using the same HOST. I did what you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Better clarification about  the simulator in comments and in another posted answer.

---

As you pointed, the PubSub emulator currently [not support](http://cloud/pubsub/docs/emulator#known_limitations%5D) the use os protobuffer messages, and that's what you are using in your code ([Snippets](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-proto-messages) from Publish / Receive messages of protobuf schema type), and its not supported currently. You can try to use [Avro schema type](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-avro-records) **or** open a `feature request` on [Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) for work with protobuffer schemas in PubSub emulator.

Comment: Yes, but I am still a little uncomfortable about it. Because when Google says. 'Schema support for protocol buffers.' is a limitation. It means, PubSub Emulator doesn't allow define a schema in the Emulator Topic creation or we can't test Protobuf msgs using PubSub Emulator? Because in my case, I'd like just to send and receive msgs using protobuf. But I can't do it using Protobuf. My code just work using real PubSub. Do you have any affirmation about it?

Comment: As understood from the snippets, seams both creation of filters using protobuf schema and publish/receive messages are not supported. The use of PubSub emulator for testing of production environments is not recommended. The better way is to have a test project for this.

Comment: The limitation that schema doesn't work with protocol buffers in the emulator only applies to the case where you create a schema and attach it to a Pub/Sub topic. There is nothing that stops you from actually sending a serialized protocol buffer as the data in a message. The limitation in the emulator has to do with the fact that the .proto parser is only available in C++ while the emulator is written in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications @KamalAboul-Hosn. Alexandre, please move or remove the acceptance if another clarification help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The "resource not found" issue would not have anything to do with Pub/Sub the emulator not supporting Protocol Buffer schemas. If you tried to use Protocol Buffers in an unsupported way (which would be creating a `Schema` object that uses `PROTCOL_BUFFER` as its `type`), then you'd get back an error specifically about the lack of support for Protocol Buffer schemas in the emulator.

Your issue looks more like one of the following:

1. The name of the subscription does not match the name of the subscription you created.
2. You did not actually create the subscription in the emulator, but instead created it in the actual Pub/Sub service.
3. You did not point your subscriber to the emulator by setting the `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable.

You should verify the subscription exists in the emulator. You can do this by running the `gcloud` tool against it. Let's assume you started up your emulator with the following command:

```sh
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=my-test-project
```

If this starts up your emulator on port 8085, you can check that your subscription exists by running:

```sh
> CLOUDSDK_API_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDES_PUBSUB=http://localhost:8085/ gcloud --project my-test-topic pubsub subscriptions list
```

If your subscription does not exist when you run that command, then it means that you likely didn't create the subscription in the emulator, but instead created it in the actual service. If you do see it, then it likely means your subscriber isn't sending requests to the emulator, but is actually sending requests the Pub/Sub service itself.